# Guardar dados e inserir na CheckBox

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Para começar vou já expor o meu problema: Depois da pessoa responsável por adicionar esse novo serviço como é que automaticamente irá aparecer no form onde está a lista de todos os serviços em forma de checkbox?

Neste momento estou a desenvolver um projeto de final de curso e a meio surgiu-me um problema que não sei como resolver.

Bem, é uma aplicação em **Visual Basic** que faz registos daquilo que um determinado aluno/professor faz na biblioteca escolar. Um dos botões que temos é inserção de um novo serviço que a biblioteca um dia mais tarde possa vir a adicionar à sua lista na base de dados. Num form à parte, iremos ter uma lista com esses dados todos da base de dados em checkbox para selecionar aquilo que o utilizador vai fazer na biblioteca para depois poder submeter.

**Formulário do registo do novo serviço**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A maneira como pensamos submeter os dados
(aqui aparecia uma nova checkbox, dependendo do que foi criado)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria interessante complementar sua pergunta com o código do seu formulário.

Comment: Ainda não existe código para isso é que pedi ajuda. Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode tentar usar um for e instanciar as checkbox manualmente ou usar um datagrid com binding.

Comment: O nosso objectivo era facilitar o trabalho da funcionária ou seja um código que automaticamente depois de inserido o serviço aparecesse nessa outra form como checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Salve os serviços numa tabela do banco de dados. Para exibir todas as opções para o funcionário, o ideal é usar um ComboBox, pois o modo de apresentação independe da quantidade de serviços. Basta fazer um `SELECT` no banco e inserir os valores nas opções da ComboBox.

Comment: Muito obrigado peça sugestão, se calhar será a melhor opção. Mas imaginemos que a biblioteca terá um novo serviço por exemplo "jogos educativos" (apenas um exemplo) e aí este será inserido na base de dados, por sua vez não há esse registo do novo serviço na hora de a pessoa responsável pela biblioteca. Aí é que está a minha dúvida.

Comment: Você vai fazer o SELECT e colocar os resultados na tela na tela que o funcionário vai selecionar a atividade que o usuário vai fazer na biblioteca. Você vai obtê-las no banco de dados, entendeu? Na primeira tela você insere, na segunda você obtém.